# React component to render price change

Tags: javascript, react.js, jsx, react-native

I've written this **[Card component](https://github.com/ytliuSVN/crypto-app/blob/bd36ecb67538d25fe1be401f7030b4338433cd28/app/components/CoinList.js)** which is composed of `thumbnail image`, `name`, `symbol`, `total_volume`, `current_price`, and `price_change_percentage_24h`.

[image]

I want to refactor my `renderPriceChange` function since it's using the same pattern.

```
const renderPriceChange = (price) => {
  if (price > 0) {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.rise}>
        <AntDesign name='caretup' color='#03AE9D' size={10} />{' '}
        {percentageFormat(item.price_change_percentage_24h)}%
      </Text>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.drop}>
        <AntDesign name='caretdown' color='#fb2c33' size={10} />{' '}
        {percentageFormat(item.price_change_percentage_24h)}%
      </Text>
    );
  }
};
```

How to make it look cleaner with smart and less code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is equivalent to:

```
const renderPriceChange = (price) => {
  return (
    <Text style={price > 0 ? styles.rise : styles.drop}>
      <AntDesign
        name={price > 0 ? 'caretup' : 'caretdown'}
        color={price > 0 ? '#03AE9D' : '#fb2c33'}
        size={10}
      />{' '}
      {percentageFormat(item.price_change_percentage_24h)}%
    </Text>
  )
}
```

You can inline the `if...else` by using JavaScript's ternary operator `a ? b : c`